# Stripe: "It's often a good idea to store an email address in metadata for tracking later"

Tags: stripe-payments

In the Stripe's [Charge documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-metadata), for the field `metadata`, there is this advice:

> It's often a good idea to store an email address in metadata for tracking later

Why? The e-mail is already set in [`receipt_email`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-receipt_email) field, isn't it?

**Why is Stripe advising to store the e-mail in the metadata too?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [`receipt_email`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-receipt_email) parameter, then Stripe will send an [email receipt](https://support.stripe.com/questions/email-receipts) to that address. You might want to create charges without sending a receipt however, so in that case it would make sense to keep the email address as a [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api#metadata) field.